# Openpyxl Color formatting bg_colour

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to fill range with RGB #00B0F0 but everytime I'm getting all black row like this.[image]
Here is the code.

```
maxrow = 5
    maxcol = 17
    # #my_blue = openpyxl.styles.colors.Color(rgb='00FF0000')
    for colNo in range(1,maxcol+1):
        for rowNo in range(1,maxrow+1):
            worksheet.cell(row=rowNo, column=colNo).fill = PatternFill(bgColor='50FFC7CE',fill_type='solid')
            worksheet.cell(row = rowNo, column=colNo).font = Font(bold =True)
```

Please help as I want to fill the range with the same RGB mentioned

Answer (score 0):

PatternFills use colours in add odd way: the colours refer to the colours in a pattern; when the fill is solid only the foreground colour, `fgColor`, is used.

From the specification:

> This element is used to specify cell fill information for pattern and
>   solid color cell fills. For solid cell fills (no pattern), fgColor is
>   used. For cell fills with patterns specified, then the cell fill color
>   is specified by the bgColor element.